# undefined error for inherited class attributes in python

Tags: python-3.8

i've created a class workingstudent that inherits from class student but the inherited attributes(name, school) are seen as undefined by the program

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, school):
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
        self.marks = []

    def average(self):
        total = sum(self.marks)
        ItemNo = len(self.marks)
        ave = (total / ItemNo)
        print(ave)

    def friend(self, friend_name):
        # return a new student called "friend_name" in the same school as self
        friend = Student(friend_name, self.school)
        return "Anna's friend is {} and he also goes to {}".format(friend.name, self.school)


Anna = Student("Anna", "st.peters")
Anna.marks = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
print(Anna.name)
print(Anna.school)
print(Anna.marks)
print(len(Anna.marks))
Anna.average()
print(Anna.friend("Alex"))


class workingstudent(Student):
    def __init__(self, workplace, salary):
        super().__init__(name, school)
        self.workplace = workplace
        self.salary = salary

    def get_salary(self):
        return self.salary

    def get_workplace(self):
        return self.workplace


workingAnna = workingstudent("google", "$10,000")
print(workingAnna.get_salary())
print(workingAnna.get_workplace())
```

when the code is run the inherited attributes of name and school in the workingstudent class are seen as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class workingstudent(Student):
    def __init__(self, workplace, salary):
        super().__init__(name, school)
```

`name` and `school` are indeed not defined here. You should pass them to `workingstudent.__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, name, school, workplace, salary):
```

then

```
working_student = workingstudent('name', 'school', 'workplace', 999)
```

BTW, per PEP8 conventions the class name should be `WorkingStudent`.

Comment: so even if i'm inheriting i need to pass the attributes of the parent class in the __init__ method of the child class? Thanks for the PEP8 reminder

Comment: @JordanRob yes, you are inheriting the **class**, not the **instance**.